# gpio on raspi and nodejs with rpi-gpio

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio

Im running raspi Model B Rev 2 512MB, I installed the module and succesfully opened a pin for writing on it. Succesfully made a LED blink.
Then I try to open a port for reading and I get and error

> { Error: EIO: i/o error, write errno: -5, code: 'EIO', syscall: 'write' }

This the relevant part of the code.

```
var gpio = require('rpi-gpio');
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:8080');

    gpio.setup(7, gpio.DIR_OUT, control);
    gpio.setup(22, gpio.DIR_IN, gpio.EDGE_BOTH, control);
```

});

```
function control(err)
{
    if(err)
        console.log("Control function: " + err);
    else
        console.log('ok');
}
```

This is the pinout I see using gpio readall, I want to read from GPIO6, therefore I call to 22 (Physical port) I also tried 25 (BCM port) with the same result.

[image]

Any clue ??

Comment: Are you running with SUDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the syntax is slightly different, if you add the third parameter for the edge you cannot add the callback, changing this:

`gpio.setup(22, gpio.DIR_IN, gpio.EDGE_BOTH, control);`

to this

`gpio.setup(22, gpio.DIR_IN, gpio.EDGE_BOTH);`

solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

PIN 6 is Ground, so you cannot use it. You can use PIN 5 for input. (PINs not GPIOs)

Pin diagram for reference:

[image]

Comment: please check my edit, I included the actual pinout and fixed the function call.